# How to plot the data for the Challenger crissi in a specific way

Tags: r

I have the following R output where the data below shows the temperature (Temp) at the time of the flight and wheather at least one primary O-ring suffered thermal distress (TD) with 1 = yes, 0 = no.

```
Temp = c(66,72,70,75,75,70,73,78,70,76,69,70,67,81,58,68,57,53,76,67,63,67,79)
TD = c(0,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0)
d = data.frame(Temp,TD)
```

This data has to deal with the Challenger mission disaster in 1986.
I am wondering what it means to construct a graph for the estimated probabilities for both the cases, where at least one primary O-ring suffered thermal distress (TD) and no primary O-ring suffered thermal distress (TD) as a function of temperature. Construct the two graphs in the same coordinate
system.

I am confused about this since the two conditions it wants us to graph for make no sense to me. It seems like you would only get constant graphs.

Comment: You just want to plot the data?

Comment: Yes, but in the way the question asks.

Comment: I don't understand in how the data wants it plotted.

Comment: This data is widely-used in test questions as an example of logistic regression. I think a web search for "R estimated probability challenger o-ring" will give you some clues :)

Answer (score 1):

The key here is *as a function of temperature*. So what is a reasonable function in this case when the outcome is binary?

The first thing that comes to mind is a logistic function.

```
plot(d, pch=20, col=2) # Half the work done.
```

Let's fit a logistic regression model to the data. Note that this will estimate the logit (log odds) by default, not probability.

```
m1 <- glm(TD~Temp, data=d, family="binomial")
```

`predict` with "type=response" will give you the predicted *probabilities* for our Temp data, not the logit (the default).

```
pr <- predict(m1, type="response"); pr
```

and you can then easily add these to the plot.

```
points(Temp, pr, pch=20)
```

But it's better to show a smooth line representing not just the data, but all possible temperatures within the range of the data. To do this, we supply more data points to the `predict` function via a "newdata" argument. This new data frame should contain all the terms from the model, in this case, only `Temp`.

```
newdata <- data.frame(Temp=seq(range(Temp)[1], range(Temp)[2], by=1))
newdata$pr <- predict(m1, type="response", newdata=newdata)

plot(d, pch=20, col=2)
lines(newdata)
```

---

[image]

Comment: But it asks for two graphs. I got this  process.

Comment: _"Construct the two graphs in the same coordinate system"_. Sounds to me like the question is asking for two graphs in one plotting device, which is what I've done. Graph 1. `plot(d, ...)`. Graph 2. `lines(newdata)`.

Comment: The first part of the question also says: _"Construct a graph ..."_. A graph = one graph.